# File as input in python netaddr

Tags: python, linux, bash, ip

Im trying to supernet list of IP networks using netaddr in python.

**Code:**

```
import netaddr
from netaddr import *
iplist = [IPNetwork('10.105.205.8/29'),IPNetwork('10.105.205.16/28'),IPNetwork('10.105.205.0/29')]
print '%s' % netaddr.cidr_merge(iplist)
```

**Output:**Which actually works.

```
[IPNetwork('10.105.205.0/27')]
```

Can I provide the input from a file? which contains IP networks in CSV files?

**IP_Network.csv**

```
8.35.196.0/23
8.35.196.0/24
8.35.197.0/24
8.35.198.0/23
8.35.198.0/24
8.35.199.0/24
8.35.200.0/21
8.35.200.0/23
8.35.200.0/24
8.35.201.0/24
8.35.202.0/23
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the netaddr module but to me it seems you are just building a list from inputs. If you have an input file with a network in each line, would this work:

```
with open ("inputfile", "r") as fp:
    iplist = [IPNetwork(q) for q in fp.read().splitlines()]
```

Hannu